# Accidentally deleted .nuget folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Well I pretty much did it.

The project still builds, strangely, and launches, however I have a lot of errors in every .xaml and .cs folder I access:

[image]

and then, in .cs files: 
[image]

help?

Comment: The `.nuget` folder is mostly useless and it normally doesn't affect anything unless the project needs a specific NuGet version. Try to close all files > close VS > open VS > Build | Clean Solution > Build | Rebuild Solution

Comment: This should be gone if you restart VS and or clean and Re-build

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `clean solution` and `rebuild` did the trick. Post as answer and I will accept